# How to specify the host in cartodb.js

Tags: carto, carto-js

We are hosting a cartodb installation ourselves which works pretty well but I can't seem to figure out how to get `cartodb.js` to call our installation instead of the one at `cartodb.com`.

Reading [the source](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/src/api/layers.js#L27-L31) it's clear that `cartodb.com` is the default host so it should be possible to somehow specify another host.

The end goal is to build the maps programmatically using cartodb.js and the sql api (if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SQL API from cartodb.js pointing to a different server you can use some options in cartodb.SQL:

```
var sql = cartodb.SQL({ user: 'youruser', host: 'host.com', protocol: 'http' })
  sql.execute('select * from table', function(data) {
...
});
```

The interesting code is here: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/src/api/sql.js#L33

Comment: Thanks! Can I specify the host when using cartodb.createLayer() as well?

Comment: it depends, are you using viz.json or createLayer with data

Comment: I'm not using viz.json. Right now I'm trying to follow the named maps tutorial at http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/named_maps.html but I'm also interested in "Anonymous maps" briefly mentioned here: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#anonymous-maps